# Is it good practice to make "app" context globally?

Tags: node.js, express

There is a way to make variables and function on Node.JS work globally using GLOBAL prefix on variables.

```
var app = express();
```

turn it to:

```
GLOBAL.app = express();
```

My afraid of this approach is about the implication of this method of memory leak or something else when the application becomes bigger.

Another way to skip this method is using outside parameter on external required functions. I.g:

```
var myFunction = require('./functions/myFunction.js') (app);
```

You can pass app if "myFunction" has support for external parameter, but on this approach you may pass every time the "app" parameter and handle it on function scope before you initialize any inner function. It's an annoying behavior although it is more "object oriented" instead.

What you guys can talk about this stuffs? Can I continually put some important variables in global scope view?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's bad practice to use any global variables in Node and there's no advantage in doing so. `app.js` can be your main loop. You can use `app.use` or pass `app` using one of these two patterns:

```
var everyauth = require('./middleware/everyauth.js');
var errors = require('./middleware/errors.js');
app.use(everyauth.middleware());
errors(app);
```

If you want your tests to start your server, doing something like this in mocha:

```
before(function () {
  require('../../app.js');
});
```

The issue isn't memory leaks; it's about minimizing dependencies in your code.